# How to toggle the buttons based on the lock and unlock using angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

i have 4 buttons, When i click on button, it must give me, whether i clicked on actual or budget button, and if it is `locked`, then the button must change to `unlock` and true or false value must go into the respective functions and the values needs to be changed in response as well.
I am not getting where i am going wrong, i need to show the buttons toggle based on click of lock or unlock budget and actuals, and need to pass these values as params for API hitting.

Please help.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrqyqx)

Ts:

```
  openUnLockBudget(type) {
   console.log(type)
    let requestParams = {
      "isLock":true,
      "type":type
    }
  }

  openLockBudget(type) {
    console.log(type)
    let requestParams = {
      "isLock":false,
      "type":type
    }
       console.log(requestParams,"lockBudget")
  }
```

Comment: Looks like you have figured it out. I can see the buttons toggle in the demo. You might want to swap the icons for 'lock' and 'unlock' buttons though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, now i am planning to make one function to handle these 4 buttons